# Equivalent of pick's theorem for a circle?

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

Consider the Pick's theorem that states that the area $A$ of a polygon placed on a grid of equal-distanced points such that all the polygon's vertices are grid points, is given by

$A = i + \frac{b}{2} -1$,

where $i$ is the number of lattice points in the interior of the polygon and the number $b$ the number of lattice points on the boundary placed on the polygon's perimeter (see [1] for a picture).

Is there somewhere a similar relation that holds for a circle on a similar lattice ?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem

Comment: The way you've phrased Pick's theorem, the correct formula is $$A = (i +b/2 - 1)\ell^2$$ where $\ell$ is the distance between adjacent grid points. The formula you gave only works when $\ell$.is required to be $1$.

Comment: The issue here is that Pick's theorem requires all vertices to be at grid points. In a circle, effectively every point is a vertex, and you cannot have them all on grid points. You might try requiring that the circle have grid points as the ends of a diameter, but I think the relationship between encircled grid points and area will still not be as simple.